# Extract and unmarshal JSON payload from response

Tags: json, citrus-framework

I'm trying to write Citrus tests for a RESTful endpoint producing and consuming `application/json` content, and I'm not sure how to get my responses unmarshalled to a Java POJO (using Jackson or whatever (un)marshaller Citrus supports).

E.g. in REST-assured, I can simply write

```
UploadResponse response = when().post("/file").as(UploadResponse.class);
```

Is there an equivalent in Citrus?

I can only find examples using `validate()` or `extractFromPayload()`, which don't really cover my use case, since I don't want to operate on scalar members but embed the entire response object in the request object for the subsequent test step.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
http().server(testServer)
      .post("/file")
      .validationCallback(new JsonMappingValidationCallback<UploadResponse>(UploadResponse.class) {
            @Override
            public void validate(UploadResponse payload, Map<String, Object> headers, TestContext context) {
                // do something with payload object
            }
      });
```

The JsonMappingValidationCallback automatically searches for a JSON ObjectMapper in Spring bean application context. You can also provide an ObjectMapper instance as constructor arg to the JsonMappingValidationCallback.